# How to make multipart feature call outs start at the same point from the annotation text in QGIS3

Tags: qgis-3, labeling, callout

I have a map showing multipart features and map text. The text is too large for the features so I want to use call outs but the call out lines extend from the text in what appears to be the shortest path, I would like all the call out lines to extend from the text at the same point. How can this be accomplished?
In the image below I was able to get some features to label the way I intended (i.e. Green Features on the Left) but the Yellow ones I couldn't without moving the text block so far away that it was off the map.
[image]

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you working with?

Comment: 3.10.13-A Coruña

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update to QGIS 3.16. There you may choose anchor-points for the callout lines at both the feature and the label.

[image]

Comment: That was easy...